# How to force awesome to respect xterm geometry settings?

Tags: awesome-wm

If I have 2 floating xterms open and open a third one, it seems the -geometry settings I give on the command line are ignored and awesome tries to figure out on its own where the third xterm should go. How do I force it to respect the -geometry setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rules, you have a `placement` property. It defaults to "place stuff on the current screen where there is the most room".

You need to remove or override this for xterm. You can do this either by adding a new rule or editing the current ones. Adding `function() end` as the placement function in an xterm specific rule should override the catch-all rule.